# Delay for width on dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, css

I am dynamically loading some HTML with a jquery get request. I take that content and insert it into the DOM. I have a callback setup that pulls the element's width and height on complete.

Here is the problem, the size is dynamically set with CSS, and the size is WRONG for the first few milliseconds after loading the content. It will be a few pixels too small, but if I add a timeout it works perfectly.

Using timeouts is not allowed under development policy to fix things like this, so I need some way to ensure the element is at its final size.

Comment: Is there an animation on DOM insertion?

Comment: Is it pertinent that it executes after a certain time? Are there any other actions a user can take that you are allowed to do that can alter the content (like when a user scrolls, the css is altered).?

Comment: There is no animation, and it doesn't happy everytime. It's like CSS is being applied async. The css isn't altered.

Comment: maybe the best solution is to add the css inline along with the elements being added.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and share the link?